# Flex Variable ButtonBar width

Tags: apache-flex

Wanted to create a button bar in flex 4.6, each button having different widths.

Application basically contains 10 NavigatorContents in ViewStack.
Button bar is binded to the ViewStack.

Now the first button should have width of 100, the second button should have width of 80, the buttons from third to seven should have width of 300 and remaining all buttons should have a width of 100.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Dear Marty, can you provide me with an example on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code for spark buttonbar to have variable button width:-

(buttonBar.dataGroup.getElementAt(0) as ButtonBarButton).width= 100; //first button
(buttonBar.dataGroup.getElementAt(1) as ButtonBarButton).width= 80; //Second button

Similarly for remaining buttons you can specify the width.